# Remove duplicate rows based on additional condition

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe with thousands of rows, that contains occasional duplicate rows. Here, duplicates are defined as rows that share an `id`.

Whenever there are duplicate rows, there is often one row that is complete (contains values in all columns), whereas the duplicate rows contain `NA` values.

Example:

```
id <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4)
val1 <- c(10,10,NA,10,20,30,30)
val2 <- c(10,NA,10,10,NA,30,40)

myinput <- data.frame(id,val1,val2)

myinput
  id val1 val2
1  1   10   10
2  1   10   NA
3  2   NA   10
4  2   10   10
5  3   20   NA
6  4   30   30
7  4   30   40
```

In this case, rows 2 (duplicate of row 1) and row 3 (duplicate of row 4) should be deleted, as they are duplicates that contain NA. Note that row 5 shouldn't be dropped (despite the NA), because it isn't a duplicate. Rows 6 and 7 are duplicates, but shouldn't be dropped, as they don't contain NA (I need this last condition because complete rows contain contradictory data that need to be checked separately, in my case).

Desired output:

```
> myoutput
  id val1 val2
1  1   10   10
2  2   10   10
3  3   20   NA
4  4   30   30
5  4   30   40
```

In summary, I need rows to be dropped on the condition that they

1. are duplicates (they have a shared `id`) AND
2. contain NA.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this simplified logic would work in your case? It does at least on the sample data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

myinput %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(starts_with("val"), .direction = "downup") %>%
  distinct(pick(everything())) %>%
  ungroup

# A tibble: 5 × 3
#     id  val1  val2
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    10    10
#2     2    10    10
#3     3    20    NA
#4     4    30    30
#5     4    30    40
```

The idea is to `fill` the `NA` values for each `id` and then only keep unique rows. What this will do is make the rows with `NA` as duplicates and remove them using `distinct`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only looking for duplicate `id` values with an `NA` in one of the value columns, in base R you can index on this logic. Since `rowSums(myinput)` returns `NA` if there is an `NA` present, a little "cheat" would be to use `is.na(rowSums(myinput)`:

```
drop_obs <- (duplicated(myinput$id) | duplicated(myinput$id, fromLast = TRUE)) & is.na(rowSums(myinput))

myinput[!drop_obs,]

#   id val1 val2
# 1  1   10   10
# 4  2   10   10
# 5  3   20   NA
# 6  4   30   30
# 7  4   30   40
```